# Infimum and supremum of subset of inclusion Power set

Tags: relations, order-theory

I'm having trouble understanding the following exercise:

Given $U=\{1,2,3,4\}$ with $A=P(U)$ the power set of the elements of $U$ and $R$ the inclusion relation over $A$.
Determine the infimum and supremum of $B$, being $B$ a subset of $A$.

a) $B=\{\{1\},\{2\}\}$

b) $B=\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{1,2\}\}$

I can't find a definition for infimum and supremum of a set where its elements aren't connected by a inclusion relation. For example on the part (a) 1 isn't included on 2 and neither 2 is included on 1, so are they both supremum and infimum at the same time? Isn't the infimum and supremum unique?

If the case was $\{\{2\},\{1,2\}\}$ I believe one could say $\{2\}$ is the infimum and $\{1,2\}$ the supremum since the first is included on the second.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure if the tags for the question are OK, if they aren't please let me know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relationships amongst the elements of $B$ don’t actually matter. For the infimum you’re looking for the largest subset of $U$ that is a subset of every member of $B$, and for the supremum you’re looking for the smallest subset of $U$ that contains each member of $B$ as a subset. (Here *largest* and *smallest* refer to the subset relation: $X$ is smaller than $Y$ in this sense if and only if $X\subsetneqq Y$.)

As an example, if $B=\big\{\{3\},\{4\}\big\}$, the *only* subset of $U$ that is a subset of both $\{3\}$ and $\{4\}$ is $\varnothing$, the empty set, so the infimum of $B$ must be $\varnothing$. There are four subsets of $U$ that have both $\{3\}$ and $\{4\}$ as subsets: $\{3,4\},\{1,3,4\},\{2,3,4\}$, and $U$ itself. $\{3,4\}$ is contained in each of the others, so it’s the smallest of them in the sense of $\subseteq$ (as well as being the smallest in cardinality, though that’s not relevant). Thus, the supremum of $B$ is $\{3,4\}$.

Now apply these ideas to your sets $B$. You might notice that the infimum and supremum can be described rather simply in terms of familiar basic set operations. Do you see how?

Comment: Ok great, I get it now, I was looking for the infimum and supremum inside $B$. I guess one could say the supremum is the smallest upper bound of $B$, thank you!

Comment: @Chapi: You’re welcome! Yes, the supremum is the least upper bound in the partial order, and the infimum is the greatest lower bound.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ be a partially ordered set. For $B\subseteq A$ we say that $a=\sup B$ if for every $b\in B$, $b\leq a$, and for every $c\in A$, if every $b\in B$ satisfies that $b\leq c$, then $a\leq c$. Namely, amongst the set of upper bounds for $B$, $a$ is the *minimum*.

The infimum is defined similarly, reversing the order and taking the maximum of lower bounds.

This is the same definition as you know from the real numbers. Only now it might be that a set might not have a supremum or infinmum, and it might have several upper bounds which are minimal upper bounds, but no upper bound is the minimum upper bound.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer for the example in your last paragraph is correct.

The "inclusion relation" on the set of subsets of a set defines just a partial order, not a total order. Many (most) pairs of sets aren't related.

Hint for a): what is the largest set that's a subset of both $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$?
What is the smallest subset that has both as subsets?

Similarly for b).

Comment: Well the largest subset would be the empty set and the smallest subset that has both as a subset would be $\{1,2\}$ but I can't see how that leads to the infimum or supremum

Comment: Now that I read Brian's answer I can understand your hint, thanks!