# Determine the supremum

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory

currently I am working on an exercise, where I have to give the supremum of $\emptyset\subset A$. The set $A$ is defined as follows:

$A:=$ {{1},{1,2},{1,3,4},{1,2,3,4}}. On this set, we define the inclusion order.

In general, the supremum is the upperbound, which is an element of $A$. Is it true that the supremum is equal to {1}, since it is contained in every other element of $A$? Is it possible that the empty set is the supremum?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wouldn't it be the other way around? If your define the order on the set as the inclusion order, isn't the supremum the subset that contains all other subsets?

Comment: @YB1998 The supremum of a subset is defined as an element $a$ in $A$ such that each element in the subset is contained in the supremum, and if you take a random element $c$ in $A$ with $x\subset c$ for every $x$ in the subset, then $a\subset c$. The empty set is contained in every set, so I don't think that it should be the subset that contains every subset

Answer (score 1):

Supremum would be the smallest set containing all the sets that you have. What you have written is the smallest contained in all the sets, which is the infimum of sets.

Notation wise, $$\sup_n A_n=\cup_{i=1}^{n}A_i\qquad\text{ and }\qquad\inf_nA_n=\cap_{i=1}^nA_i$$

> So, your answer is $\{1,2,3,4\}$. $\{1\}$ is the infimum.

Comment: Is {1,2,3,4} the supremum of $\emptyset$, which is a subset of $A$? For me it makes more sense that {1,2,3,4} would be the supremum of $A$, and not the empty set.

Comment: what do you mean by the supremum of a single set?

Comment: if you have $\phi,\{1,2,3\},\{4\}$, say. Then yes, the supremum would be $\{1,2,3,4\}$. If you have trouble understanding, go by the definition. Supremum of the sets is the union of the sets you have.

Comment: @Sam I don't think  any collection of subsets can have a supremum $\phi$ unless your collection ONLY includes $\phi$. Any other set and the set itself (or superset, if you have more sets) becomes the supremum. Try going through https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1824929/562589 to understand this better.

Comment: @Sam I think you are making a confusion here. The empty set is a subset of $A$, as it is a subset of every set. But the empty set is not a member of $A$. For every $a \in A$, we have $$\sup\{a\}=\inf\{a\}=a,$$ but that doesn't apply to $\varnothing$. Your confusion is perhaps with the empty supremum of elements of $A$, that is, $$\sup\varnothing=\sup\{a:a\in\varnothing\},$$ and that is $\{1\}$, because it's the least member of $(A,\subseteq)$ (I suppose that is the underlying order relation). You can verify this claim by applying the definition. Likewise $\inf\varnothing=\{1,2,3,4\}$.